# Iframe does not change after updating html

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe in my main page connecting to another smaller html page. When I change the small page, the older version is shown in my main page.
At first I thought it was a cache problem so I inserted this to the beginning of the small page but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache" />
<meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache" />
<meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0" />
```

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl + F5, Usually works for me, otherwise open it in incognito mode.

Comment: It most likely is caching. Adding those lines to the page now won’t do anything because it’s already cached. Right click in the iframe and choose the option the reload the frame contents.